# Get List<GraphUser> from executeAndWait() for Facebook integration on Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, list, facebook-graph-api

I know how to asynchronously do a `Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session,Request.GraphUserListCallback)` and in the callback method you have access to the `List<GraphUser>` element. The question is how do you do this in a background thread.

What I have so far is

```
Request friendsRequest = new Request(session,"/me/friends");
Response response = friendsRequest.executeAndWait();
GraphObject obj = response.getGraphObject();
```

How do I convert `obj` to a `List<GraphUser>` or is there a better way and I'm just missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it to get me through right now. but I don't know if this is the best  way.

So what I did was just grab the whole JSON response from facebook and parse out what I wanted.

```
try {
    Request friendsRequest = new Request(session, "/me/friends");
    Response response = friendsRequest.executeAndWait();
    JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(response.getRawResponse());
    JSONArray data = responseJSON.getJSONArray("data");
    if (data.length() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject friend = (JSONObject) data.get(i);
            String name = friend.getString("name");
            String facebookID = friend.getString("id");

            // Do Stuff With name and facebookID

        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (FacebookException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Make sure to catch the `FacebookException` otherwise you'll get force closes when the user has no data connection